# Probability of getting ace after getting a king

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Consider a regular 52 card deck of playing cars.  Suppose 2 cards are drawn at random from the deck with-out replacement.  What is the probability that the second card is an ace, given that the first card is a king?

Comment: is this homework?.. if it is, flag it as such.

Answer (score 5):

When a king is missing from a deck how many cards are left and how many of them are aces?

Comment: It's been 7 years! I hope Craig has found the answer!

Comment: Normally I'd write an answer but it looks like homework, even though not flagged as such. In homework questions responses that don't directly answer the question but guide the questioner to an answer are common. And this is a pretty direct guide. If you can answer my question then you can easily calculate the solution.